# TStringGrid doesn't draw scrollbars

Tags: c++builder, scrollbars, tstringgrid

I have a form with TStringGrid component on it. Property **Scrollbars** of TStringGrid is set to *ssBoth*. If i make the window smaller, scrollbars doesnt appear. Instead of this client area of TStringGrid is cropped. I would prefer if scrollbars were disabled if application window has enough size and automatically enabled if I shrink window size under critical value. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using? The `Scrollbars` property has always worked fine for me.

Comment: Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171 
Copyright © 2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: It has something to do with window size. If I enlarge window size about threshold value, scrollbar appear. Maybe I had set incorrect anchorses because this time I have no problem.

Comment: Its very probably that this problem was due to anchors:right & anchors:bottom were not set. I had simulated this situation, scrollbars are not displayed if application window is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thruthseeker got it. If you haven't either anchored the grid, or otherwise auto-scale it to the size of the window, then it won't change size with the window, and thus won't have its own scroll bars.